# ng-include with ng-init oddity

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I created an inline template like so

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/deviceResultsContainer.html">
    {{resultListTitle}}
</script>
```

If I use it like so

```
<div ng-include="'/deviceResultsContainer.html'" ng-init="resultListTitle = 'Errors'"></div>
<div ng-include="'/deviceResultsContainer.html'" ng-init="resultListTitle = 'Warnings'"></div>
```

My output is

> Warnings
>
> Warnings

Why would it be listed like this, as opposed to what I'd expect:

> Errors
>
> Warnings

Comment: ng-include does not create new separate scope, write directive if you want to parametrize template this way

Comment: totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `$scope` value `resultListTitle` is being set to 'Warnings' last.  They are technically both looking at the same value.

I think what you are looking for you probably want to have a directive with *isolated* `$scope`.

If you would do the following:

```
<div ng-include="'/deviceResultsContainer.html'" ng-init="resultListTitle = 'Errors'"></div>
<div ng-include="'/deviceResultsContainer.html'"></div>
```

You would see this:

> Errors
>
> Errors

Comment: Is there a way to get around it other than write a directive?

Comment: Not for what you are looking to do.

Comment: why this fear of writing directives ? this is the most powerful tool of angular...

Comment: I think ng-repeat will give you different scopes. That is a directive though :)

Comment: @PierreGayvallet It always seems like overkill to me for something that just does HTML reuse. If I needed logic re-use I can understand the use of directives

Comment: @PierreGayvallet If I wanted just basic HTML re-usage do I have any other option than writing a directive?

Comment: not really, at least none proper. directive with just "template" and "restrict : E" attribute is less fragile than an ng-include call, more easy to extend / add behaviour, to refactor/move ... but if you really dont want to, as @AmyBlankenship said, using ng-repeat would create scopes and fix your ng-init issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you add `ng-if="true"` or some variation of a truthy statement it will change the order of evaluation to where `ng-init` gets re-evaluated before `ng-include`.  It's a hack for sure, so use at your own risk.